# How to find substring from string?

Tags: c++, c

How do I find a substring from the string path "/user/desktop/abc/post/" using C/C++? I want to check if folder "abc" is present or not in that path.

Path is character pointer `char *ptr = "/user/desktop/abc/post/";`

Comment: `strstr()` or `std::string::find()`.

Comment: This is 2 questions in 1, C and C++ are two totally different languages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C, use the `strstr()` standard library function:

```
const char *str = "/user/desktop/abc/post/";
const int exists = strstr(str, "/abc/") != NULL;
```

Take care to not accidentally find a too-short substring (this is what the starting and ending slashes are for).

Comment: hmm.. what if it's the last part of the path?

Comment: what happen if "/user/desktop/abc" then how findout "abc" folder.

Answer (score 40):

Use `std::string` and `find`.

```
std::string str = "/user/desktop/abc/post/";
bool exists = str.find("/abc/") != std::string::npos;
```

Comment: what happen if "/user/desktop/abc" then how findout "abc" folder

Comment: std::string::npos, its compare with initial position ? I am not getting what you told to j"ust check if it's the last position."?

Comment: @user1511510 no, `npos` is returned by `find` if the substring wasn't found.

Comment: I am not getting what you told to "just check if it's the last position." in the case "user/desktop/abc", how to findout "abc" folder?

Comment: @user1511510 oh... well, I'm not going to write the code for you. Can't you figure it out yourself? It's just treating a corner case, I hope you can manage.

Answer (score 11):

Example using [`std::string` find method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (){
    std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
    std::string str2 ("needle");

    size_t found = str.find(str2);
    if(found!=std::string::npos){ 
        std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
first 'needle' found at: 14.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strstr(const char *s , const char *t)`
and `include<string.h>`

You can write your own function which behaves same as `strstr` and you can modify according to your requirement also

```
char * str_str(const char *s, const char *t)
{
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) 
{
for (j=i, k=0; t[k]!='\0' && s[j]==t[k]; j++, k++);
if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
return (&s[i]);
}
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This function looks more complicated than supposed to be... Why you are returning "nothing" at the end since function should return int parameter?

Comment: You can write your own, but doing so will in most cases be wrong. The functions in the c library are usually more efficient and better tested than the stuff you write yourself.

Comment: Yeah sure it can fail in some cases but ... i tried and i did that so thought of pasting it here...

Answer (score 0):

As user1511510 has identified, there's an unusual case when abc is at the end of the file name.  We need to look for either `/abc/` or `/abc` followed by a string-terminator `'\0'`.  A naive way to do this would be to check if either `/abc/` or `/abc\0` are substrings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *str = "/user/desktop/abc";
    const int exists = strstr(str, "/abc/") || strstr(str, "/abc\0");
    printf("%d\n",exists);
    return 0;
}
```

but `exists` will be 1 even if abc is not followed by a null-terminator.  This is because the string literal `"/abc\0"` is equivalent to `"/abc"`.  A better approach is to test if `/abc` is a substring, and then see if the character after this substring (indexed using the pointer returned by `strstr()`) is either a `/` or a `'\0'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *str = "/user/desktop/abc", *substr;
    const int exists = (substr = strstr(str, "/abc")) && (substr[4] == '\0' || substr[4] == '/');
    printf("%d\n",exists);
    return 0;
}
```

This should work in all cases.

Comment: *"`exists = (substr = strstr(str, "/abc")) && (substr[4] == '\0' || substr[4] == '/');` should work in all cases"* - not so... given say `"/abcd/abc"` you'll choke on the `d`... to do it properly, if the `substr[4]` test fails you need to resume the search further into the string.  (It's probably easier to add a trailing '/' before searching for `/abc/`.)

Comment: @TonyD Good catch!  I agree completely, feel free to edit the post.

Answer (score -1):

If you are utilizing arrays too much then you should include `cstring.h` because it has too many functions including finding substrings.

Comment: You mean, we dont have any standard function to find out the substring from the string.