# I need to find the length of a substring beore a word in C

Tags: c

let say I have the string " I own many pets".
How can I find the length of the string before the word "many" in C?

Comment: Did you look at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+find+substring)? The answers should get you at least towards a partial solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find substring from string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195353/how-to-find-substring-from-string)

Answer (score 2):

Just find the index of the first occurence of "many"

You can use the [`strstr()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strstr.htm) function to do this, and just find the difference between the pointer returned by `strstr()` and the pointer to the whole string.

As pointed out by @4386427 this solution may not work if we talk about words (**word ≠ substring**).

So if you want to do something with **words** you will have to check if there is a space character before and after your substring (and handle the cases when the word is at the beginning or the end of the string you search the substring in).

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: `His face is rather small` - find the length before the word `is` .... maybe `strstr`alone is not the solution

Comment: @thedude What have you tried so far and what don't you understand?

Comment: @4386427 It depends if we are talking about words (characters between space characters) or substrings. But then you can still do your own `findwordinstr()` function from `strstr()` if we are talking about words. But it's fine if we talk about substrings.

Comment: i want to replace a word in a string with another word, but that word does not have to be the same length. I can do it if they are the same length but I don't know how to do it if they are different lengths.  I though of just stitching together there strings to do that. but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @vmonteco - the title and question clearly tells this is about a word - not about a sequence of characters. Therefore your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Michi - I did not intend to say `strstr` could not be used for this problem. I only stated that `strstr`alone would not do it.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to replace a word in a string with another word, but that word
>   does not have to be the same length. I can do it if they are the same
>   length but I don't know how to do it if they are different lengths. I
>   though of just stitching together there strings to do that. but I am
>   not sure how to do it.

Finding each word in the string uses `strstr(mystr, " ");`  Assuming that there is only one space between words (just to make the analysis simple), create a while loop using `start` and `end`. Each word begins at `start` and has the blank after the word in the end pointer. Set up the array of pointers using this loop

```
/* This assumes there is only one space between words
   It also assumes there are no leading or trailing blanks
   The assumptions are just for ease of analysis.
*/
char str[] ="This is a simple string";
char *start = str;
char *end = NULL;
int count = 0;
char mystring[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_SIZE];
while(end = strstr(start," "))
{
     len = end - start;
    // copy the substring into the array using strncpy()
    strncpy(mystring[count], start, len);
    // add the final '\0' character to the string in the array
    mystring[count++][len] = '\0';
    start = end + 1;
}
// Copy the last substring int the array
// end is now NULL but the substring ends with '\0'
// Thus a plain strcpy() is all that is required.
strcpy(mystring[count], start);
```

You should set up your list of words as an array of pointers. I will give this as a set of steps rather than code so that you can build the code yoursel

1. Create an array of pointers to strings.

   char *mystrings[MAX_STRINGS];
2. Split the large sentence string into individual words and put each word into a separate string. You can use malloc to create the appropriate sized buffer.
3. Identify the pointer that has the word you want to replace.
4. Create a pointer to the new word and put it into the array
5. Free the old pointer.
6. concatenate the strings in the array into a new string using `strcat()`.
7. Free the pointers and make sure that you do not overrun the final buffer when you do the `strcat()`

Another alternative is to create a two dimensional character array.

```
  char mystrings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_SIZE];
```

Use a similar process, except use `strcpy()` to copy the words into the buffers. The replacement of the old word is also done with `strcpy()` and you do not have to free the old pointer. Again make the new sentence as a string using `strcat()`. Note that since `strcpy()` puts the final NUL character in place, it does not matter that the two words are different sizes as long as you do not overrun the buffer. Similarlt `strcat()` would put the final NUL in place to make the resultant string as long as you do not overrun the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check first if the `sub string` is found, if found print its position `-1`.

Try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void checkString(char *string1, char *string2);

int main(void){
    char test[256] = "I own many pets";
    char string2[] = "many";

    checkString(test, string2);
    return 0;
}

void checkString(char *string1, char *string2){
    char *s1, *s2, *s3;

    size_t lenstring1 = strlen(string1);
    size_t lenstring2 = strlen(string2);

    if (lenstring2 < 1){
        printf("There is no substring found");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t i=0,j=0;
    int found=0;

    s1 = string1;
    s2 = string2;


    for(i = 0; i < lenstring1; i++){
        if(*s1 == *s2){
            s3 = s1;
            for(j = 0;j < lenstring2;j++){
                if(*s3 == *s2){
                  s3++;s2++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            s2 = string2;
            if(j == strlen(string2)){
                found = 1;
                printf("The length is %zu\n", i);
              }
          }
        s1++;
    }

    if(found == 0){
        printf("No match Found");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The length is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *replace(char *str, char *old, char *new)
{
    char *ret;
    int lold, lnew;
    char *pos = strstr(str, old);

    if(pos == NULL)
       return NULL;

    lnew = strlen(new);
    lold = strlen(old);
    ret = malloc(1+strlen(str)+lnew-lold);
    if(pos != str)
        strncpy(ret, str, pos-str);
    strcat(ret, new);
    strcat(ret, pos+lold);
    return ret;
}
```