# Finding a Pair of character in a string

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, stl, substring

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int count = 0;
        vector<string> v;
        string resp;
        cin >> resp;
        v.push_back(resp);
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), "xy") != v.end()){
                count++;
        }
        cout << count << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I want to find the character "xy" in the string for multiple test cases. 
For input xy, my count value outputs correctly as 1.

But for the input xyxxy instead of 2 it gives the value as 0
It is only finding the value once but i want to check the count of xy in whole string

I tried to use the substring function as well but it failed to work

Comment: Why are you including a non-standard include file?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "xy" within a vector of strings, which in your example, has a single element, "xyxxy". Since "xy" is not equal to "xyxxy", you're not finding any matches.

But even if you tried to `std::find` "xy" within "xyxxy" itself - that would fail too, since `std::find` looks for a *single element* within a range (or rather, iterator pair).

Instead, you can use the `string::find()` method, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195353/how-to-find-substring-from-string); or, as the case may be, `std::string_view::find()`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    const std::string needle{"xy"};
    std::string haystack;
    std::cin >> haystack;
    std::size_t count{0};
    std::string_view remainder{haystack};
    while(true) {
        auto first_pos = remainder.find(needle);
        if (first_pos == std::string_view::npos) { break; }
        count++;
        remainder = remainder.substr(first_pos+needle.length());
    }
    std::cout << "Found " << count << " occurrences of \"" << needle << "\"\n";
}
```

Note: This does not account for overlapping occurrences. If you want those, you could either always increase the starting position by just 1; or make your solution more complex by employing something Boyer-Moore or Knuth-Morris-Pratt search (see [String search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm)), and resuming it at the correct state after each occurrence found.

Comment: it uses more memory space. Do you have any solution which takes minimum space complexity ?

Comment: @RAGHAVENDRADUBEY: This uses `O(1)` extra space; I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps you're confusing `std::string_view` and `std::string`?

Comment: @RAGHAVENDRADUBEY: Send you my what? At any rate, the answer is probably no.

Comment: Can you help me in my recent question ?

Comment: I am getting a TLE error using this solution. S can contain only letters X and Y. And S is a size of N. And N's size is between 1-10^5. the sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 3⋅

Comment: @RAGHAVENDRADUBEY: I don't know what you're compiling and running and with what inputs. But - maybe it's just the fact that the program takes different inputs than the the program in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the idea of while loop but that worked for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i(0); i < str.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        if ((str[i] == 'x') && (str[i + 1] == 'y'))
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    std::cout << count;
}
```