# Searching a vector for a string, and then find the position of the string in c++

Tags: c++, file, vector, find, erase

I am trying to erase a string from a text file. To do this, I want to read the file into a vector, then I want to search for the position of this string, so I can use vector::erase to remove it. After the string has been erased from the vector, I can write the vector into a new file.

So far, I have made all of that, but finding the position of the string. I've found all sorts of solutions using < algorithm > 's std::find, but those answers were trying to check if this string exists, not its position.

Here is an example of how the text file is set up. With a string, followed by an integer, followed by .txt without spaces. Each string is on a newline.

```
file123.txt
Bob56.txt'
Foo8854.txt
```

In this case, the vector would be "file123.txt", "bob56.txt", "Foo8854.txt".

This is the code I have made already:

```
std::vector<std::string> FileInVector;
std::string str;
int StringPosition;

std::fstream FileNames;
FileNames.open("FileName Permanent Storage.txt");
while (std::getline(FileNames, str)) {
  if(str.size() > 0) {
      FileInVector.push_back(str); // Reads file, and this puts values into the vector
  }
}

//This is where it would find the position of the string: "bob56.txt" as an example

FileInVector.erase(StringPosition); // Removes the string from the vector
remove("FileName Permanent Storage.txt"); // Deletes old file
std::ofstream outFile("FileName Permanent Storage.txt"); // Creates new file
for (const auto &e : FileInVector) outFile << e << "\n"; // Writes vector without string into the new file
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find substring from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195353/how-to-find-substring-from-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Below](https://onlinegdb.com/Ngy-Gk92w) is the working example. There is **no need to store the string into a** `vector` or search for the position of the string inside the vector because we can directly check if the read line is equal to the string to be searched for, as shown.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    
    std::string line, stringtobeSearched = "Foo8854.txt";

    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    
    std::ofstream outFile("output.txt");
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
            //if the line read is not same as string searched for then write it into the output.txt file
            if(line != stringtobeSearched)
            {
                outFile << line << "\n";
            }
            //if the line read is same as string searched for then don't write it into the output.txt file
            else 
            {
                std::cout<<"string found "<<std::endl;//just printing it on screen
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file could not be read"<<std::endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    
   
    return 0;
}
```

**input.txt**

```
file123.txt
Bob56.txt'
Foo8854.txt
file113.txt
Bob56.txt'
Foo8854.txt
file223.txt
Bob96.txt'
Foo8814.txt
```

**output.txt**

```
file123.txt
Bob56.txt'
file113.txt
Bob56.txt'
file223.txt
Bob96.txt'
Foo8814.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::find` returns an iterator to the found element and `std::vector::erase` accepts an iterator too. `std::distance` can be used to compute the index if needed.

Small example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>


void print(const auto& vec){
    for(const auto& e:vec){
        std::cout<<e<<' ';
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> vec{"a","b","c","d"};
    auto it = std::find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"c");
    
    if(it!=vec.end())//If found
    {
        std::cout<<"Index "<<std::distance(vec.begin(),it)<<'\n';
        vec.erase(it,it+1);
        print(vec);
    }
}
```

Output:

```cpp
Index 2
a b d
```

That said, there is simple `O(1)` memory ( in terms of loaded lines) solution: read the lines and immediately write back only those that do not match the string.

Comment: `std::distance(vec.begin(),it)` vs `it` ?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин What do you mean?

Comment: same as `it` . /

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Sorry, can you elaborate please? `it` is not the same as `
std::distance(vec.begin(),it)`. The latter returns a number, the former is an iterator, not an index.

Comment: it was `.find()`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин `std::vector` does not have any `find`. I do not understand what are you trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::vector<std::string> b{"uyv","uky","u6t"};
    std::vector<std::string> cb{"uyv"};

    auto heil = std::search(b.begin(), b.end(), cb.begin(), cb.end());
    b.erase(heil);
    for (auto c : b)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;


}
```